# php use $_Get to include a .php

Tags: php

at the moment a friend and I are working through a PHP tutorial. We are both new to php, but have some general experience in other languages.

We want to include "testseite.php" into our index.php The "testseite.php" is in the folder content/articles

The way the tutorial does it is to use

```
include("content/articles/".$_GET['include']);
```

but if we do that there is the following error:

> Warning: include(/users/xxx/www/users/xxx/www/myCms/content/articles) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /users/flateric/www/users/flateric/www/myCms/index.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'content/articles/' for inclusion (include_path='.') in /users/xxx/www/users/xxx/www/myCms/index.php on line 5

We thought ourselves that the problem might be, that it doubles the username (i changed it to xxx) and "users" and "www" in the path.
Thanks for your help

Comment: The error says, there is no directory 'content/articles/'

Comment: This is such a bad idea... You're trusting user input to access files

Comment: if we manually include it via include("content/articles/testseite.php"); it is correctly displayed

Comment: it probably is, but this is the only way atm, we know of to include this page.

Comment: A tutorial showing usage of `include()` based on a GET variable should be abandoned as soon as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, `include` means to load the file into the arguments, like loading a library. So, this error means the file /users/flateric/www/users/flateric/www/myCms/index.php does not exist. You should evaluate if the `$_GET` value points to a physical file.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `$_GET['include']` is empty (or the `include` key is non-existent).  This is causing the filename to include to be wrong.  You're expecting to include a file named this:

```
content/articles/testseite.php
```

but actually getting an include for this:

```
content/articles/
```

Clearly, this is incorrect and causes the error.  If the `$_GET` params don't include the `include` value (or it's blank), you should probably consider another approach, such as providing a default value or generating an error to the user.

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error message : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory